# Displaying images inline with PHP & CSS

Tags: php, html, css

---

I am echoing images out on a page using php but the images and info go down the page like so:

```
1
2
3
```

I need them inline, is there anyway to do this?
Here is what I have:

```
<?php
echo '
     <div class="auction_box" style="height:150px">
         <form name="myform" action="http://hffhfghfhf.net/testing.php" method="POST">
             <p> </p>
             <p> </p>
             <p> </p>

             <img src="http://hfhfghfgh.net/'.$battle_get['pic'].'" height="96px" width="96px"/><br/>


             Name:<br/>' .$v->pokemon. '<br/>
             Level:' .$v->level. '<br/>
             Exp:' .$v->exp. '<br/>

              </form>
     </div>';
     }
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: Try and take the time to properly code block when posting. There is a preview area so that you can see everything is neatly presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `float: left;` to the `.auction_box` class, I think?

Comment: Apply `display:inline-block` instead?